# Script does not resume after for loop

Tags: python, pandas

New to Python and having some issue understanding why the scripts doesn't execute when running the entire thing (F5). If I run it line by line, it works.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [7559.583, 7821.127, 7888.402, 7971.666, 8013.122 ]}

dfd = pd.DataFrame(d)
dfd.rename(columns={"col1": "Date"}, inplace=True)
dfd.rename(columns={"col2": "Price"}, inplace=True)

tempcalc = []

for x in range(len(dfd['Price'])):
   tempcalc.append(dfd['Price'][x+1] / dfd['Price'][x] - 1)


tempcalc.insert(0,np.nan)

dfd['DailyReturns'] = tempcalc
```

---

The code seems to stop for some reason after the loop - I feel like I'm missing something really basic here.

Comment: I don't see a `print` statement anywhere. How are you confirming that execution really does stop immediately after the for-loop?

Comment: are you getting an error?

Comment: Your code calls for the sixth row of your dataframe in the last loop  (the `x+1` part ), but you dataframe has only five rows. That's why the loop can't finish and the rest of your script doesn't run.

Comment: this code will produce an index error, as your Price columns length is 5 (since your df has 5 rows) so when you try to do `dfd['Price'][x+1]` you will get an error on the last iteration since x+1 will try to look up an index 1 greater than the number of elements you have

Comment: This is a simple indexing error these kinds of questions should not be asked.Try to read the error statement carefully. It always shows how to resolve the problem

Comment: Yes as  I said earlier you are missing very basic Indexing error

Comment: I understand my indexing mistake - I have to get used to things starting with "0" here vs. with "1" like in R! Thanks all!

Answer (score 0):

You have index problems:

```
for x in range(len(dfd['Price'])):
   tempcalc.append(dfd['Price'][x+1] / dfd['Price'][x] - 1)
```

You go from range 0 to 4 but in your calculation you try to access the row/index 5 which doesn't exist and it results in a key error.

```
for x in range(len(dfd['Price'])-1):
   tempcalc.append(dfd['Price'][x+1] / dfd['Price'][x] - 1)
```

So you want to reduce it by one. You already had the thoughts in your programming when you added an empty row with:

```
tempcalc.insert(0,np.nan)
```

when you print it it will result into:

```
   Date     Price  DailyReturns
0     1  7559.583           NaN
1     2  7821.127      0.034598
2     3  7888.402      0.008602
3     4  7971.666      0.010555
4     5  8013.122      0.005200
```

Answer (score 0):

Your indexing is wrong. Indexing is starting from 0 not 1 so do this correction

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 1000)

d = {'col1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], 'col2': [7559.583, 7821.127, 7888.402, 7971.666, 8013.122 ]}

dfd = pd.DataFrame(d)
dfd.rename(columns={"col1": "Date"}, inplace=True)
dfd.rename(columns={"col2": "Price"}, inplace=True)

tempcalc = []
print(dfd)
for x in range(len(dfd['Price'])-1):

    tempcalc.append(dfd['Price'][x+1] / dfd['Price'][x] )
tempcalc.insert(0,np.nan)

dfd['DailyReturns'] = tempcalc
```

Look in the for loop for correction in range function, it should upto one less than end

Answer (score 0):

Also, another way to do what you're looking for, way more efficient and avoiding loops:

```
dfd['DailyReturns'] = dfd['Price'].shift(-1) / dfd['Price'].shift(1)
```